# AS3 - dispatchEvent from class and addEventListener in main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to create a dispatchEvent inside my class that loads data.

Inside my 'loader_complete' method (class):

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("bam",true));
```

On my main timeline:

```
this.addEventListener("bam", getResults);   

function getResults(e:Event){
    trace('hi');
}
```

I have extended the class to 'extends EventDispatcher {' as well.

What am I missing?

thanks,

Comment: Is your class that loads data a child/descendant of your main timeline?  If it's not display object and a descendant of the main timeline, the event will not bubble up - you'll have to add the event listener on the instance of the class that dispatches the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely cause in this situation:

Your custom class that extends `EventDispatcher` is not on the display list - eg. the instance of it is not a child/descendant of your main timeline.

When an event bubbles, it bubbles up the display list parentage until it reaches the main stage.  If the object dispatching the event is not a display object with a parent, there will be no bubbling.

You can either add the event listener to the instance of the custom class that loads data:

```
     myCustomClassThatLoadsData.addEventListener("bam",getResults);
```

Or pass in a reference to a display object (main class, main stage, etc) to dispatch the event on.

```
stage.addEventListener("bam",getResults);
myCustomClassThatLoadsData = new CustomClassThatLoadsData(stage);

//in the custom class
stageReference.dispatchEvent(new Event("bam"));
```

Comment: @BotMaster I don't want to get in the middle of this but the answer was correct. I just don't know who to credit. lol. Confused....

Comment: @Sky - I don't really care who you credit... I simply took my comment and made an answer out of it.   Typical Stackoverflow guidline is you upvote any answer you found useful or a helpful contribution, and mark the one that was the most helpful in your specific case as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Sky They do both seem to be correct. Vote them both up if you find them both helpful, and if you wish. LDMS did go the extra step of some extra helpful information, too.